# How to Redirect User Another Page

Tags: html, xslt

```
    <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="/doc/paymentHistory/paymentList/paymentlistlength='1>
             <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
                       javascript:OpenBrWindow('portal?cmd=dekontView&amp;AVPaymentDate=document.getElementsByName('AVPaymentDate')&amp;lang=tr','Preview','resizable=no,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,status=no,menubar=no',990, 590,'true');
 return false;
            </script>

              <xsl:when>

        </xsl:choose>
```

After some controls i would like to redirect user to another page.I've tried above code it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
...
<script>
    document.location.href='http://www.java2s.com';
</script>
...
```

Comment: hello now i need to open pop up.I tried <script>
    window.open='http://www.java2s.com';
</script> but it didn't work.any suggestion?thank you

Comment: it's better to create separate question; and even better to do some search first (GIYF) - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp